# javascript read variable value from URL

Tags: javascript

When i post data from one page to another,how do i get that into dom.

say URL is www.test.com/?xxx=1234&a=122

How to get **xxx** and **a** value inside DOM?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get query string values in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters in the URL are available as the *search* property of the [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) object. It's not too hard to convert it to an object for easy access:

```
function getURLValues() {

  var search = window.location.search.replace(/^\?/,'').replace(/\+/g,' ');
  var values = {};

  if (search.length) {
    var part, parts = search.split('&');

    for (var i=0, iLen=parts.length; i<iLen; i++ ) {
      part = parts[i].split('=');
      values[part[0]] = window.decodeURIComponent(part[1]);
    }
  }
  return values;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I find this to be a much easier way of doing it. But other methods work too.

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
const xxx = params.get("xxx")
const a = params.get("a")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic tutorial on one way to do what you are asking:

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html

Basically, you split the location string from the url into an array, separating by &, after the ? sign.

Here is the code from that page that does this:

```
// Read a page's GET URL variables and return them as an associative array.
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash; 
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&'); // cut the URL string down to just everything after the ?, split this into an array with information like this: array [0] = "var=xxx"; array [1] = "var2=yyy";

   //loop through each item in that array
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        //split the item at the "="
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');

        //put the value name of the first variable into the "vars" array
        vars.push(hash[0]);

        //assign the value to the variable name, now you can access it like this:
        // alert(vars["var1"]); //alerts the value of the var1 variable from the url string
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

I've added some comments to explain it.

Comment: :How to get the iframe URL in facebook

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean?

Comment: Not a very good tutorial, e.g. it doesn't decode the values or replace '+' with ' '. I can't see how jQuery helps here at all.

Comment: If you read all the way through he eventually just makes it into a little extension for jQuery. But no, jQuery doesn't help it at all. I was just trying to show a basic way to do it, I've used this method before as I've never had to worry about anything with +s in it.

Comment: It's also not considered good style to use an Array where an Object will do. With an object, there is no need to use *push*, you just assign directly to the property (as is done with the array). I can't see any point in assigning the values to the array's numeric members.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `window.location.search` property of javascript (More details on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)).

```
var str = window.location.search;
```

Now you can use the string manipulation functions like `substring` or `split` to get the text you desire which can be used "inside the DOM".